# Flat list is not smooth as the error says

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

The error says: "VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to 
update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow 
React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, Her's what i do?

1- On component will mount i call a function and this function dispatch a request to my action in this case  **retrievExploreFeed(this.state.limit, this.state.offset)** again this function retrieves data and put it to my redux store. As you can after the promises is resolved i get data from my props and put in to resultSet array. and when the next fetch is called which is another function it returns next batch of results and append to the resultSet.

---

by using the new_offset as 0 and limit as 20 if i call the function to get results from the api the api will return a result set of 20 records with a new_offset of 20. and again im using the new_offset returned from the api this case 20 and putting into the next call to fetch data. the next iteration the api will give 20 results with new_offset of 40. and so on

---

```
this.state = {
      loading: false,
      resultSet: [],
      limit: 20,
      offset: 0
};

componentWillMount() {
    this._fetchResult();
}
```

Here the api returns new_offset every time. by using the new_offset im 
getting the next batch of results (I mean the next page, sort of)

```
  _fetchResult = () => {

        //calling action and getting the initial results
        //filling the result set using redux store and putting to state
        //Getting the new offset and putting into state

        this.props.actions.retrievExploreFeed(this.state.limit, 
        this.state.offset)

              .then(() => {
                    this.setState({
                          resultSet: this.props.exploreFeed.data,
                          offset: this.props.exploreFeed.new_offset,
                          isLoading: false,
                          isRefreshing: false
                    });
              });
  }
```

The next call from flat list as soon as it reaches the end
onEndReached={()=> this._fetchResultNextResult()}
onEndReachedThreshold={0.7}

```
_fetchResultNextResult = () => {

        console.log('next fetch is called');

        const myHeaders = new Headers({
              'token': constants.TOKEN
        });

        fetch(`${constants.API}?tag=product_list&limit=${this.state.limit}&offset=${this.state.offset}`, {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: myHeaders,
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(payload => {

              this.setState({
                    resultSet: [...this.state.resultSet, ...payload.data],
                    offset: payload.new_offset,
              });

        });

  };
```

---

### FlatList

```
<FlatList
       data={func.formatData(this.state.resultSet, constants.COLUMS)}
       numColumns={constants.COLUMS}
       onEndReached={()=> this._fetchResult()}
       onEndReachedThreshold={0.7}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       removeClippedSubviews
       getItemLayout={(data, index) => {
                const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
                return { length: width, offset: width * index, index };
       }}
       renderItem={(info) => (
              <ProductGrid
                      data={info.item}
                      showProduct={this._productSelectedHandler}
               />
     )}

/>

-------------------------------------
Product Grid as pure component
--------------------------------------

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions } from '   react-native';

import * as constants from "../../Constants/api";

class ProductGrid extends PureComponent {



  render() {

        const { id, data, showProduct } = this.props;

        if (data.empty === true) {
              return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
        }

        return (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={showProduct.bind(this, id)}>
                    <View style={styles.item}>
                          <Image
                                style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
                                source={{ uri: data.product_image }}
                          />
                    </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    }

};
```

Comment: How many results get fed to the list at once?

Comment: 20 as you can see, i have supplied limit as the parameter to the function that returns the result.

Comment: Also i have update my question about limit

Comment: One guess might be to try "removeClippedSubviews". I feel that the number of items you're showing probably isn't the issue then - I have a list with 200-300 items without getting this error

Answer (score 1):

I think you're seeing the performance hit because your rows are of a variable size - and so the size of each row has to be calculated on render.

You can either filter out the empty rows before you pass the data to the FlatList, and/or use `getItemLayout` to specify the heights of each row.

> `getItemLayout` is an optional optimization that let us skip the measurement of dynamic content if you know the height of items ahead of time.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i think the problem here is everything is rendered at once. Lets say on scroll i go to the bottom of the screen and my "_fetchResultNextResult()" function is called and i append the newly retrieved data from api and append to the old result array like this "resultSet: [...this.state.resultSet, ...payload.data]" and then when the render happens only the newly added results should be rendered right?. As you can see I have used pureComponenent in my render component. Why is the pureComponent not working?

Comment: It's all rendered at once because of what David said. It doesn't know the height so it doesn't know what it's rendering. His answer is correct.